# Autohotkey delay all input

Tags: input, delay, autohotkey

I'm trying to write a script that will delay all the physical keystrokes I send. This includes key down, key up and the duration that the key is being held down.

So far I got

```
a::
    if( not GetKeyState("a"))
    sleep 1000
    sendinput {a down}
return

a up::
    sleep 1000
    sendinput {a up}
```

But the problem is, for reasons I can't fathom, not every stroke is delayed. When the key's been held down, the next few presses and releases aren't delayed at all.

I guess it'd also be appropriate to ask if there's a way to simply delay all my input whether with AHK or other applications instead of doing such a script for every key.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using Autohotkey to add an artificial delay to a keypress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29224910/using-autohotkey-to-add-an-artificial-delay-to-a-keypress)

Answer (score 0):

Add the prefix `$` to the hotkeys.

> This is usually only necessary if the script uses the Send command to send the keys that comprise the hotkey itself, which might otherwise cause it to trigger itself. The $ prefix forces the keyboard hook to be used to implement this hotkey, which as a side-effect prevents the Send command from triggering it. The $ prefix is equivalent to having specified #UseHook somewhere above the definition of this hotkey.
>
> [v1.1.06+]: #InputLevel and SendLevel provide additional control over which hotkeys and hotstrings are triggered by the Send command.

**Source**: http://ahkscript.org/docs/Hotkeys.htm#Symbols

Answer (score 0):

In the first place, I can't imagine a way to delay the key release properly in an easy way..

The following is a bad workaround. I'd be pretty interested in a better solution, too.

```
aUp = false
delay_when_pressing_down = 200
delay_between_sends = 10
return

$a::
    aUp = false
    delay_start := a_tickCount
    sleep 1000
    send a
    sleep, %delay_when_pressing_down%
    if aUp = true
    {
        time_a_was_pressed_down := time_of_release - delay_start
        time_a_was_pressed_down -= %delay_when_pressing_down%
        start := a_tickCount
        loop
        {
            now := a_tickCount
            diff := now - start
            if diff > %time_a_was_pressed_down%
                break
            send a
            sleep, %delay_between_sends%
        }
        return
    }
    loop
    {
        send a
        sleep, %delay_between_sends%
        if aUp = true
        {
            start := a_tickCount
            loop
            {
                send a
                sleep, %delay_between_sends%
                now := a_tickCount
                diff := now - start
                if diff > 1000
                    break
            }
            break
        }
    }
return

$a up::
    time_of_release := a_tickCount
    aUp = true
return

^e::reload
```

Comment: Works much better then my attempt, only problem is the key doesn't register when the delay's timer is running. So unfortunately this currently doesn't delay "all" keystrokes as it is.

Comment: I start feeling really bad because of the amount of amateurness in my post. Anyways, I'm not sure if I understood your concern, but I added some lines. Might work the way you expect it to now.