# Using Autohotkey to add an artificial delay to a keypress

Tags: delay, autohotkey

I am trying to use autohotkey to add an artificial delay to a keypress.  I am in a tiled room, with a mechanical keyboard, and a desktop microphone.  I would like to add an artificial delay of approximately 1/10 of a second to my PTT key, so that others don't hear the audible CLICK when I press the key.  I ended up binding the key to something else "numpad -" so that capslock could be the key I actually press.  This is the script I ended up with.

Expected result: pressing capslock presses numpad- on a 0.1s delay, and then holds the key until I release capslock(and it should also unpress capslock on release)

Actual result: It works, but if I press and release it too quickly, it holds "numpad -" down and capslock down, and releases neither.

code:

```
#UseHook

*~Capslock::
    sleep, 100 
    Send {NumpadSub Down}
    sleep, 100
    While GetKeyState("Capslock")
    {

    }
return

*~Capslock Up::
    sleep, 300
    Send {NumpadSub Up}
return
```

without the sleeps as is, the program opens the key, closes the key, and then re-opens.

Comment: In case anyone else cares, here's how I solved it.  Of course, I've been working on this for days, and I fix it as soon as I make a post making me look like an idiot.

Answer (score 1):

## UseHook

Answer:

```
*~Capslock::
        sleep, 100 
        Send {NumpadSub Down}
        keyWait, Capslock, U
        sleep, 100
        Send {NumpadSub Up}
    return
```